# javascript loop freezes browser and can't see change before loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, freeze

I have a simple javascript loop as you seen below:

```
function runCode() {
    $("#sample-span").removeAttr("style");
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        console.log(new Date());
    }
    $("#sample-span").toggleClass("colorized");
}
```

That toggle class of span in the page as below:

```
<span id="sample-span" style="color: orange;">Sample Text</span>
<input type="button" value="click to run" onclick="runCode()" />

<style>
span {
    color: blue;
}
.colorized {
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

The problem is that when the loop is running the page freezes and can't see that span color changes.

How can I solve this problem?

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/tuz7z364/25/)

**UPDATE**

Dear all, `console.log(new Date());` is just a sample, you assume that here is running heavy javascript procces.

Comment: Why are you logging a `new Date()` 100000 times ? That is extremely expensive.

Comment: Dear @GhassenLouhaichi, this is just a sample, assume that here is running heavy javascript procces.

Comment: Then you have to split up your process into asynchronous code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add a small delay after changing the color before running the heavy process:

```
function runCode() {
  $("#sample-span").toggleClass("colorized");
  setTimeout(runTask,10)
}

function runTask(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    console.log(new Date());
  }
  $("#sample-span").toggleClass("colorized");
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tuz7z364/9/)

Comment: This works, but still browser freezes. Is there any way to prevent browser from freezing?

Comment: You can't. Javascript is blocking by nature, if you run a heavy process browser stops and freezes, its normal

Comment: Well you could fix the freezing by artificially slowing down the process, by setting a 1 milisecond timeout for every part of the heavy process: setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(new Date());
    },1);

Comment: Thanks. I have had a browser freeze, and the fix is `const now = new Date()` outside the loop, plus `setTimeout(, 0)`. It still freezes by 2-3 sec, though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that the javascript task queue executes all available code in your function before performing DOM manipulation. Meaning that the class toggle calls are registered, the loop is executed, then the toggles are executed successively so you cannot see the color change.

What you need to do is send the second part of your function to the end of the task queue like follows :

```
function runCode() {
    $("#sample-span").toggleClass("colorized");
    // allows the first toggle to execute and sends the loop and the second
    // toggle to the end of the task queue
    setTimeout(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
            console.log(new Date());
        }
        $("#sample-span").toggleClass("colorized");
    }, 0);
}
```

I have reduced the number of iteration to reduce the browser lock, you can still see the color change still.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to actually do? If you want the text to be shown as red and then toggle back after a specified time what you're really looking for is a setTimeout.

```
  $("#sample-span").toggleClass("colorized");

  setTimeout(function() { $("#sample-span").toggleClass("colorized") }, 1000);
```

Answer (score -2):

It's because you are toggling class twice on a button click. 
If you want to change color of the span when it finishes then write: `function runCode() {
    $("#sample-span").toggleClass("colorized");
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    console.log(new Date());
  }
}`

Comment: because i want to toggle color twice

Comment: Whilst it might be true you want to toggle it twice, the man did specify in his post 'if you want to change the color when it finishes', no reason to downvote this answer. Its 100% correct. You didnt really specify what you want to happen on click, it might be interpreted either way.

Comment: I think he was pretty clear in his post @Dellirium. This is an incorrect answer and doesn't address the problem OP is facing in the slightest

Comment: Ok when is the first time when it's second time ? 
Because your code makes it toggle twice, and that is why you don't see the change.
@Shard He told: "The problem is that when the loop is running the page freezes and can't see that span color changes." - I made the code where you can see that the color is changing :)

Comment: @Shard no he was very obscure in fact, nowhere does it say that he wants to 'have color shown' while the code is running, you can only interpret it that way... he might want to run the code and keep the color for all we know. Its called toggle, so you click it again to run it again and turn it off. Who knows, it was not stated, and im pretty sure Radovan thought exactly this, so the OP needs to clerify his post, and since he didnt at the time of this answer, it is therefore not incorrect.

Im not saying its what OP wanted, its just wrong to assume that he either did or did not...